# uWSGI + python urllib2 very slow

Tags: python, nginx, flask, urllib2, uwsgi

I have a huge problem :) Here is the story: I have 2 web apps running on one server. Each started by uwsgi via supervisor (nginx there too). One project(app2) makes HTTP requests through the urllib2 to other(app1). When I start siege (siege -d1 -r10 -c200 http://app1.mydomain.com/test) The other project(app2) starting to be non-responsive and all uwsgi workers of that app2 is becoming busy. Mean time app1 is responsive from browser like it's not under "siege". And all workers becoming busy just from time ti time. When I remove that line with urllib2 and start tests all projects feeling good. Uwsgi config for the apps:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /var/run/core/app1.sock
max-requests = 5000
listen = 2048
master = true
processes = 30
harakiri = 15
harakiri-verbose = 1
buffer-size = 65536
stats = /tmp/app1_stats.sock
```

They are absolutely identical. And pay attention please that I'm not "sieging" the app wich makes HTTP requests. If it matters all made with Flask. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a problem. If someone interested: just using urllib3 and creating HTTPConnectionPool().

Comment: any other details ?  i've had similar issues before too.